# conditional DirectoryIndex in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, conditional-statements

Is it possible to make the DirectoryIndex value in a `.htaccess` file conditional based on IP, so that - for example - my IP see's `DirectoryIndex` as index.html and everyone else sees `DirectoryIndex` as index.php?

Is there a solution other than `mod_rewrite`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no conditional for DirectoryIndex. You could simulate that with a mod_rewrite directive like this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} your_ip
RewriteCond -d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index.html
```

If you want to exclude other visitors of the site from viewing index.html then also use

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !your_ip
RewriteRule (.*)/index.html$ $1/index.php
```

Comment: yeah, that was going to be my fallback if it wasnt possible. if no-one else has another solution i'll accept this.

Answer (score 2):

Using the provided information I beleive the following is what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^your_ip$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index.php

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^your_ip$
RewriteRule index.php$ index.html
```

So that only your IP can see index.php and everybody else will see index.html

or possibly:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^your\.ip\.000\.000$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
```

Comment: This is working for me, but how can I add muliple ip's?
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^your\.ip\.000\.000$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php


thanks