# htaccess conditional statements based on server name/path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, conditional-statements, if-statement

Is it possible to write some conditional "if" statements in htaccess based on the server name/path?

I know I can use `<IfModule>` but that doesn't solve the problem when the development and production server are identical.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test the value of *SERVER_NAME* or *DOCUMENT_ROOT*:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =foo
RewriteRule …
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} =/path/to/document/root/
RewriteRule …
```

Comment: This only allows me to set different rewrite rules based on the server, right? what about php flags, etc?

Comment: @cmpscabral: You can do the same with PHP with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: Gumbo,

You already answered my question in another post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599717/conditional-directoryindex-in-htaccess

thanks, I'll still mark your answer as correct