# Conditional Directory Index In Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, directoryindex, ifdefine

This relates to the question in:

[conditional DirectoryIndex in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599717/conditional-directoryindex-in-htaccess)

The answer states that the following should work:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^127\.0\.0\.0$ owner
<IfDefine owner>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !owner>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfDefine>
```

I am not sure this works, the setting of the Env var deffinately does, but no matter what IP I visit the site from the DirectoryIndex is always index.php

Is there something wrong with the conditional or should I be using something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up using the following to achieve what I wanted

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^my\.ip\.000\.000$
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of [`<IfDefine>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine); it checks defines passed to `httpd` at the command line, not environment variables. Use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)'s `%{ENV:variable}` lookup in [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) if you want to test environment variables.